# What should the size argument be in the call to VideoWriter?

Tags: python, ipython, opencv

I copied this from https://theailearner.com/2018/10/15/creating-video-from-images-using-opencv-python/  :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
 
img_array = []
for filename in glob.glob('C:/New folder/Images/*.jpg'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width,height)
    img_array.append(img)
 
out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)
 
for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
out.release()
```

It generates this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0b74fd51f292> in <module>
     10     img_array.append(img)
     11 
---> 12 out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)
     13 
     14 for i in range(len(img_array)):

NameError: name 'size' is not defined
```

Comment: The only way I could imagine that this could happen is if `glob.glob('C:/New folder/Images/*.jpg')` returned nothing, meaning that `size` was never defined. Please verify if it is or not. Also, is that a valid directory on your computer? Are there images in it?

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. What ended up being the issue?

Comment: The file path was wrong, so that fixed the 'size' problem. The code reads all the jpgs now but it only puts the last jpg into the video file.

Comment: Reading through the comments on the site you linked, one of the author's comments is "**only images with the size equivalent to your last image will be included in the video**". I assume you would've already looked through all those comments before posting here, but just to make sure, have you checked that all the images are the same dimensions?

Comment: @RandomDavis Good catch. That did turn out to be a problem, but not the problem posted here. I did have to resize all my images to a consistent size.